# Can we download the word form of quote template

Tags: cpq, steelbrick

How do I download a word form of a quote template in Salesforce CPQ? I've created a quote, added lines and generated the document. On the document I've changed the document output field to "Word".

How do I download it now? Also is there an alternative way where a user can choose PDF or Word document to download the quote template?

Answer (score 2):

To allow the user to choose the output type, there is a custom field on the user record called **Allow Output Format Change**. See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_allow_user_output_format.htm&type=5.

I think once you enable this on your user record, you'll be able to get the Word version of the template.